# using ms healthvault sdk in mono/linux

Tags: c#, mono, healthvault

The MS Healthvault SDK comes with a dll, that is necessary for programming with Healthvault. Is there a way to build an HV application in mono?

Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the assembly (dll) using the Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA). Just follow the guide and the tool will show you if there are any potential issues (unimplemented methods, P/Invokes, etc) with using it with Mono.

http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Comment: This is not a good idea. The first thing is to check HealthVault SDK EULA to see whether MS gives you permissions to use that SDK (any part of it) on non-Windows platform.